# function data_uri does not display image in IE 11

Tags: php

Have folder `images_directory`, where is located image with name `3-1-0ed11dcd9c267816f5849c900e671a5d.gif`

In root directory created php file.

Set image name without extension

```
$val_img_ = '3-1-0ed11dcd9c267816f5849c900e671a5d';
```

This is the function

```
function data_uri($file_to_get_contents, $mime) {  
$contents = file_get_contents( ''. $file_to_get_contents );
$base64 = base64_encode($contents);
return ('data:' . $mime . ';base64,' . $base64);
}
```

Take the image

```
$val_img_ = glob( 'images_directory/'. $val_img_. '*' );
```

and echo

```
echo '<img src='.data_uri($val_img_[0] , 'images_directory/').'>some image<br/>';
```

Works in FF, Chrome and Opera, but in IE 11 get this

[image]

Tried to paste this code (to test)

```
echo'<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////
wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4ML
wWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw=="
alt="Base64 encoded image" width="150" height="150"/>';
```

Works. So seems something wrong with the function? Any ideas where may be problem?

Tried `View source` and see starting with

```
<img src=data:images_directory/;base64
```

But correct must be

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64
```

Tried instead of `images_directory` in `data_uri($val_img_[0] , 'images_directory/')` to use `image/gif`, but got error...

Added to function this `$mime = 'image';` Seems all works!

All this i need because do not want to show (in View source) actual path to image file.

Comment: So if you need `data:image/gif` then why do you pass `images_directory` to `data_uri` function?

Comment: And what error did you get when pass `image/gif` to your function?

Comment: Try with `"` around src attr: `'<img src="'.data_uri($val_img_[0] , 'images_directory/').'">`

Comment: @u_mulder I simply did not understand how all works. Seems now understand. I as i wrote, inside the function added `$mime = 'image';` and all works. Seems all works with `gif`, `jpg` even without `image/gif`